# Connect C# WebApp from Azure AppService to an application running inside another Azure VM

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, database-connection

I have an application running in Azure with AppService.
Iam Using EventFlow with an Eventstore and MongoDB configuration. 
These DBs are running external from the application. The application is an ASP.NET Core 2.2
Razor Pages application.

I don't know if I just need to open some ports or something to guarantee a connection to other API s, that are deployed on Azure too.

I would try to deploy Event Store and MongoDB on another Azure VM and let the application connect to it.

Comment: I think your scenario is not totally clear.
There are several ways to connect things in Azure, for example the service bus.
You could also open a port on the VM and go with an API.

Comment: Ok I am thinking of many possibilities, Iam just searching for a good explanation that offers one possible solution. Thing is I think I would open a port and then connect over it.